# I have a hive table with 5 columns in hive and there is no data loaded for this table and the table is not partitioned

Tags: hiveql

I have a HiveQL table with 5 columns, and there is no data loaded for this table, and the table is not partitioned.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp;
```

Here are the types of the columns:

```
emp_id int
emp_name string
emp_dept int
businesseffectivedate date
```

**How can I convert `businesseffectivedate` to a partition key?**

Comment: No choice but `DROP` then redefine table. What you want to do is remove a column from dataset (i.e. from data files) and have Metastore manage that column to spawn sub-ditectories. That's a big structural change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.